# Powershell script for bulk updating Windows Updates on many pc's

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I have this script:

```
Invoke-WUJob -ComputerName comp-1,comp-2,comp-3 -Script {ipmo PSWindowsUpdate; Get-WUInstall -Install -AcceptAll | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log  } -Confirm:$false -Verbose –RunNow
```

and after execution I get this:

> Invoke-WUJob : PSWindowsUpdate module missing on destination machine
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-WUJob -ComputerName 1002-hk-ws-001,1002-hk-ws-002,1002-hk-ws-0 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Invoke-WUJob], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleMissing,PSWindowsUpdate.InvokeWUJob

I used these commands below on every PC to install to PSWindowsUpdate and setup winrm and it still does not work:

```
winrm quickconfig -q 

winrm set winrm/config/client ‘@{TrustedHosts="comp1,comp2,comp3"}’

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

the windows update cannot use remotely, maybe the hardening, you could work with a schedule task Register-ScheduledJob -scriptblock { get-windowsupdate -acceptall}

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are in a workgroup mode, vs Domain joined machines by virtue of what you said you did on each host.

You have to be an admin on the target to run this.

> [about_Remote_Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd315349(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Unless you make additional configs.

[You Don’t Have to Be An Administrator to Run Remote PowerShell Commands](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/you-dont-have-to-be-an-administrator-to-run-remote-powershell-commands/)

Thus, you need to pass credentials in your code, if you are not already running your PowerShell session with admin creds for the remote targets. This is really PowerShell remoting 101 and a well-documented use case.

Your error is saying the module is not on the remote host or can't be found.

Windows updates are a machine-level thing. So, the import should be to the AllUsers PowerShell profile not some individual user of the machines. There is extra work to get PSRemoting working on workgroup systems. For domain-joined, hosts, you can enable it using GPO. No need for extra steps.

See the steps here:

> [Enable PowerShell Remoting on a standalone (workgroup) computer](https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-powershell-remoting-on-a-standalone-workgroup-computer/)

Running code on remote systems will always run in the user context that you started, regardless of who is on the remote target.

Comment: Ok so now I'am getting a different error :

Invoke-WUJob : You can not find requested file . (Error HRESULT: 0x80070002) At line:1 char:1 + Invoke-WUJob -ComputerName 1002-ski-ws-003,1002-ski-nb-002 -Script {i ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WUJob], FileNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,PSWindowsUpdate.InvokeWUJob

Comment: I've installed everything on remote machines to : Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate but it looks like it still does not see the module ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so now I'am getting a different error :

Invoke-WUJob : **You can not find requested file . (Error HRESULT: 0x80070002)**
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WUJob -ComputerName 1002-ski-ws-003,1002-ski-nb-002 -Script {i ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WUJob], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,PSWindowsUpdate.InvokeWUJob

I've installed everything on remote machines to : **Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate** but it looks like it still does not see the module ?